# Detached house chimney removal uk

Tags: chimney, building-regulations

Hi I am having a house renovation and we have removed the central chimney stack from the house. The house is detached and the Stack removed from the roof, bedroom and ground level rooms. What’s left is the concrete base of the chimney. We have joists and wooden floors. I have told the contractor that they need to also remove the concrete base but he’s saying it’s not necessary. I’ve read online that this should be removed. Are there specifically any building regs I can point him to to back up my case ?

Comment: I dont see why its necessary

Comment: Rising damp rotting floorboards and joists ?

Comment: So builder experience is trumped by online opinion - which has not been there to see the actual situation and you don’t provide any photos either.

Comment: I’m just looking for someone who knows the building regs regarding this. My last house renovation I had the same situation and the builder removed all the base down to ground level. He said that was the regs. So I’m just hoping someone can back this up with evidence of what the regs say.

Comment: Your local building department will know all of the regs for your location.  Unknown how UK does it, but usually there are the national regs and there might be slightly different specific local regs to follow.

Comment: @crip659, put that comment as an answer.   It is  THE    answer.

Comment: You should have asked the local authority before starting… did you check whether you need planning permission or if it falls under permitted development? Had you asked first you would have been assigned a building control officer or you could have hired an approved inspector.

Comment: Yes we have planning permission for the development and also an inspector but they deal directly with the builder and I have never had the opportunity to see or speak with them. I will be calling them this morning (May as well get my monies worth)

Answer (score 1):

Your local building department will know all of the regulations for your location.

Unknown how UK does it, but usually there are the national regulations and there might be slightly different specific local regulations to follow.

This way you will know you have right regulations to follow if it needs to be removed or if it is an option to leave it in place or remove completely.  A builder or someone else might be mistaken about the regulations or they might have been changed.  The building department will look them up in a book of regulations and give you the most correct and up to date version.

Comment: Thanks I will call them Monday. :)